Django Collectstatic loads directly to STATIC_ROOT instead of S3 bucket
I've been trying this for about 24 hours now non-stop.
Here's my settings.py:

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

DEBUG = False
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Static settings for S3
STATICFILES_STORAGE = storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_S3_REGION_NAME')

STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com/static/'
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com/media/'

# Add a proper static root in case of local fallback
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# AWS-specific options
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = True
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False  # Optional, useful if you want files to be public

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INTERNAL_IPS = ['127.0.0.1']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp.apps.myappAppConfig',
    'storages',
    'debug_toolbar',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

if DEBUG:
    MIDDLEWARE.insert(1, 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware')

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS = [
    'debug_toolbar.panels.versions.VersionsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.timer.TimerPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.settings.SettingsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.headers.HeadersPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.request.RequestPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.sql.SQLPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.staticfiles.StaticFilesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.templates.TemplatesPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.cache.CachePanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.signals.SignalsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.logging.LoggingPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.redirects.RedirectsPanel',
    'debug_toolbar.panels.profiling.ProfilingPanel',
]

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',  # This will log everything at the DEBUG level
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',  # Force Django to log everything at DEBUG level
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'storages': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',  # Force storages to log everything at DEBUG level
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'boto3': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',  # Force boto3 to log everything at DEBUG level
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'botocore': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',  # Force botocore to log everything at DEBUG level
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}


Every time I run collectstatic it skips trying to send it to S3 and collects the files in local STATIC_ROOT. I've tried commenting out STATIC_ROOT but then it throws an error about needing it for the static app.
When I import my credentials from .env using boto3 and use a standard script, it uploads just fine.
I have no clue what's going on here. Everything looks great. I've run collectstatic with --clear and diagnosed this with GPT-4 from every angle.
I was previously using whitenoise as an installed app to host images from the server, but that is commented out and I've deleted all pycache info.
Any ideas?

What version of Django are you using?

Great question! And indeed this is the correct answer - the problem was with the fact that STATICFILES_STORAGE was deprecated as a way to connect to the S3 backend as of just last year. I was using Django 5.1, and that setting was deprecated in 4.2 which was released Apr 2023. Hence why there's not any StackOverflow articles, GPT-4, or even Reddit posts covering it.
Instead of using STATICFILES_STORAGE, it's recommended to consult Django documentation for the new "STORAGES" method of connecting to S3 if anyone's reading this in 2024 or later.

For Django versions 4.2 or later (Apr 2023):
Instead of (deprecated)
STATICFILES_STORAGE='storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

Use
   STORAGES = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage',
},
'staticfiles': {
    'BACKEND': 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage',
},
}

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-STORAGES
